# read mutiple characteristic from BLE and reading a string

Tags: java, android, c, bluetooth-lowenergy, cypress-psoc

So I have two question.
Let's start with the first one, how do you make two `readCharacteristic` after eachothers? the code I've showed is what I was thinking you could do it. But because `onCharacteristicRead` isn't called yet in the first `readCharacteristic` call the next `readCharacteristic` isn't triggered. Here i solved it by calling the second `readCharacteristic` in the if-statement for the first `readCharacteristic` in the `onCharacteristicRead`, but i don't know it this is normal/stupid solution?

```java
public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        BluetoothGattService mBluetoothGattService = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString(CSUuid));
        if (mBluetoothGattService != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection State: Service characteristic UUID found: " + mBluetoothGattService.getUuid().toString());
            mCharacterisitc = mBluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(UuidRead));
            mCharacterisitc2 = mBluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(UuidRead2));
            Log.w(TAG, "Connection State 1: mCharacterisitc " + mCharacterisitc + " " + mCharacterisitc2);
            readCharacteristic(gatt, mCharacterisitc);
            //I know I have to wait for the above is done, but can I do it here instead of
            //calling the line under in onCharacteristicRead? 
            readCharacteristic(gatt, mCharacterisitc2);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection State: Service characteristic not found for UUID: " + UuidRead);
        }
    }
}
```

Next question is a bit hard I think?

`the code is made in PSoC creator 4.3`

So at the moment I read a single int from my `PSoC 6 BLE` device, and another letter 'M' converted to a integer and back to a 'M' on the app-side. The reason I only read a SIGNLE 'M' is because I don't know how to send a `whole string` like `'Made it'`. I think the issue I'm having is on the `PSoC side` where I don't know how to `read a whole string`.

```c
for(;;)
{
    /* Place your application code here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aeip0hkc4YE*/
    cy_stc_ble_gatt_handle_value_pair_t serviceHandle;
    cy_stc_ble_gatt_value_t serviceData;
    
    //this is the variables I've declared earlier in the code
    //static uint8 data[1] = {0}; 
    //static char * ValStr;
    
    //here I just have a simple Integer which count up every sec
    serviceData.val = (uint8*)data;
    serviceData.len = 1;
    
    serviceHandle.attrHandle = CY_BLE_CUSTOM_SERVICE_DEVICE_OUTBOUND_CHAR_HANDLE;
    serviceHandle.value = serviceData;
    
    Cy_BLE_GATTS_WriteAttributeValueLocal(&serviceHandle); //sending the data to -> OUTBOUND
    
    //this part should probably not be in a for-loop, but for now it is.
    ValStr = "Mads Sander Hoegstrup"; //I want read whole string on my android APP
    serviceData.val = (uint8*) ValStr; //this only takes the 'M' and thats the only variable I can read from my APP not the rest of the string
    serviceData.len = 1; //Does not help to increase, if it's more than 1 I read 0 and not a letter
    
    serviceHandle.attrHandle = CY_BLE_CUSTOM_SERVICE_DEVICE_OUTBOUND_2_CHAR_HANDLE;
    serviceHandle.value = serviceData;
    
    Cy_BLE_GATTS_WriteAttributeValueLocal(&serviceHandle); //sending the data to -> OUTBOUND_2
    
    data[0]++;
    CyDelay(1000);
}
```

Here you can see that I revice the right values, a Integer and a String, but only the letter 'M' and not the string 'Mads Sander Hoegstrup'

[image]

Just ask if you want more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better ask two separate questions, since they have nothing to do with each other.

I'll answer the first question. You cannot wait inside the `onServicesDiscovered` method between the two reads. Even if you wait for 30 seconds it will not work. The reason is that only one thread can run a callback on each `BluetoothGatt` object at the same time, and it's the caller of `onCharacteristicRead` that clears the internal gatt busy flag which otherwise prevents you from submitting another request. You'd better implement some queue mechanism to keep the code cleaner if you like.

Comment: So i should make the two calls seperate so `onServicesDiscovered` is called with lets say 600ms delay between?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. In the onServicesDiscovered, call the first readCharacteristic. Then in onCharacteristicRead, call the second readCharacteristic. onCharacteristicRead will be called again but this time don't read anything.

Comment: Okay thats also the solution i went with, but i was just wondering if that was how you whould do it normally, but thanks ;)